# How to prevent the console window from opening when fire FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, full-trust

FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync always opening console window, it is possible to prevent this?

Comment: Don't create a console mode app.

Comment: Yep, i have to change from Console App to Windows App, BIG THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can prevent the console opening windows creating a manifest file.

1. In Visual Studio, right-click on your full-trust process project and
   select "Add" -> "New Item".
2. In the "Add New Item" dialog box, select "Application Manifest File" and give it a name.
3. Open the manifest file and find the  element.
4. Inside the `<windowsSettings>` element, add the following XML code:

`<consoleSettings>`

`<windowsConsole xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">`

`<showWindow>false</showWindow>`

`</windowsConsole>`

`</consoleSettings>`

With this manifest file in place, the console window will no longer appear when the `FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync` method is called.